# RemoveUserFromSite failing (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, spservices, soap

I've created this function to delete a user from my site collection.

```
function removeUserFromSite(){
  userHTML = $('#my_SiteUsers option:selected').text();
  //check if default user selected  alert(user);
  if(user!="default"){
    var removeConfirm = confirm("You are about to delete "+userHTML+" from SharePoint. Are you sure?");
    if(removeConfirm){
      $().SPServices({
        operation:"RemoveUserFromSite",
        userLoginName: user,
        async:true
      });
    }
  }else{
    alert("Please select a user");
  }
}
```

Error I get in firebug: **This operation is available only for a web with unique permissions**

I don't understand why I get this if I'm deleting from the Site Collection, what could the collection be inhering from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've [discussed this](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/459741) in the SPServices discussions. It's not a good idea to delete users from a Site Collection even if you could.

From my reply on the thread above:

> Think about the instances where the user created or modified content.
>   All of a sudden that content will have no Author or Editor. In some
>   instances, you will even get the dreaded "An unexpected error has
>   occurred".
>
> Managing permissions is the way to go, even if it is painful. Avoid
>   the pain by managing permissions wisely as you go along.

Comment: Hey Marc, yea I've sense moved around from trying to do this. I'm probably going to start working on a way to find users who aren't in groups. At least that way I can clean things up. If you have any tips for that, that would be great. Thanks for the reply.